# ASP.net VB HTTPS Post Tab Delimited File

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, https, http-post, csv

I need to post a tab delimited file via the https post request. I need to be able to do this in asp.net VB. I have found various methods in C# however as I am still rather new to asp.net VB I certainly do not have the ability to translate the C# version.

Any examples or links to examples would be greatly appreciated. The link it posts to is password and username protected. I need to post the file in the message body. Below is an example request that it needs to produce:

```
 Post <URL> 
 Authorization: Basis <Encoded Username & Password>
 Content-Type: text/xml
 <Parameter>: <Value>
 message-body: <Data>
```

Thanks in advance for your time all

Comment: that's not really a programming issue. you are just looking for code. I would suggest using Google for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here

How to generate tab delimited file in VB.Net

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=609242
http://p2p.wrox.com/pro-vb-net-2002-2003/41915-write-tab-delimited-text-file.html
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/486d3a26-6070-4a13-8d5c-7b54a6e6a58b

Can you clarify what you mean by saying "I need to post a tab delimited file via the https post request"? and I will update this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Basically the api I am trying to integrate with requires me to post a batch file (in this case in the form of a tab delimited file) in the message body of a HTTPS post that I need to generate to a given url.

Comment: it's still not clear what needs to be done. without seeing api noone will be able to help as there might be multiple implementations

Comment: I have figured out how to do the request. Now it is just trying to send the tab delimited file via https. any ideas?

Comment: HTTPS is a protocol. You can call a webservice on HTTP or HTTPS, depending on how it's setup. There's no difference in calling these two. You need to find out how the api is expecting to receive the data